# ExtJs dynamically set axes maximum value

Tags: extjs, axes

I would like to dynamically change the axis maximum limit of an ExtJS 4.x chart.

I tried using a listener `beforerefresh` but this has no effect:

```
var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
...
listeners: {
      beforerefresh(me, eOpts)
      {
        // set y-axes to max(raw_value)
        console.log('before refresh');
        // set maximum axis value of Y axis to 0.1
        me.axes.getAt(1).maximum = 0.1;
      }
    },
```

The code is reached, but using `me.axes` does not seem to have any effect at all.

What is the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17843866/how-to-give-dynamic-axes-minimum-and-maximum-values-to-chart-from-store-sencha-t

Comment: @YasuyukiUno AFAIK this is not a duplicate as the old link you post refers to a different version of ExtJS, with a different API.